# Two wrapfigures above each other with multiple paragraphs

Tags: floats, paragraphs, wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

I have this following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{r}{0.35\textwidth}
%\vspace{\baselineskip}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the cumulative sum.}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Cumulative Sum} visually inspects the similarity between the distributions per column, the cumulative sum of each column for both $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ on top of each other are plotted.
This gives a thorough understanding of a column with just one plot, and works for both categorical and continuous columns. Note that this plot does not give any insights into the relations between columns, giving it limited representational power for the whole table. 

\begin{wrapfigure}[]{r}{0.35\textwidth}
%\vspace{-5\baselineskip}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the distribution.}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Distribution} 
simply shows the distribution of the values of each column plotted with the value on the x-axis and the probability on the y-axis. The bar chart in the background of the figure shows how often values from a certain range (bin) appeared in this specific column of each, $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$.

\paragraph{Correlations} is the fourth visualization. It shows a association table for the real and synthetic data. It gives a clear understanding of what columns have associations with each other, and shows where the synthetic data diverges, indicating struggles that the model had with learning this relationship. Associated columns are coloured in red, disassociated columns in blue. For univariate datasets like the MonthlyMilkProduction dataset this plot was not being created, as it would just be completely red as this dataset only contains one column.
\vspace{3\baselineskip}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the correlations via an association table.}
\label{fig:exampleasso}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want the two wrapfigures to be above each other, and the third figure under the text. This does not work out quite well, also I receive warnings. Does anyone know how to avoid this warning and make it look more nicely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You need to put both image in the same `wrapfig` and set number of vertical lines, which it span, accordingly. Also I would remove added vertical space between text and followed figure and define caption style (see MWE below):

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, , belowskip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf,
            format=plain,
            ]{caption}  % new

\begin{document}

    \begin{wrapfigure}[16]{r}{0.35\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{An example of the visualization of the cumulative sum.}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{An example of the visualization of the distribution.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph{Cumulative Sum} visually inspects the similarity between the distributions per column, the cumulative sum of each column for both $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ on top of each other are plotted.
This gives a thorough understanding of a column with just one plot, and works for both categorical and continuous columns. Note that this plot does not give any insights into the relations between columns, giving it limited representational power for the whole table.

\paragraph{Distribution}
simply shows the distribution of the values of each column plotted with the value on the x-axis and the probability on the y-axis. The bar chart in the background of the figure shows how often values from a certain range (bin) appeared in this specific column of each, $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$.

\paragraph{Correlations} is the fourth visualization. It shows a association table for the real and synthetic data. It gives a clear understanding of what columns have associations with each other, and shows where the synthetic data diverges, indicating struggles that the model had with learning this relationship. Associated columns are coloured in red, disassociated columns in blue. For univariate datasets like the MonthlyMilkProduction dataset this plot was not being created, as it would just be completely red as this dataset only contains one column.
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the correlations via an association table.}
\label{fig:exampleasso}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Added vertical distance after captions

[image]

**Addendum:**
Caption settings used in my answer you can make valid only in `wrapfigure`. For example, by use of `etoolbox` package you need to modify preamble as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}            
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}%
{
\linespread{.84}\selectfont
\captionsetup{skip=1ex, belowskip=2ex,
          font=small, labelfont=bf, % this may you move to caption package options
          format=plain}
}

% document body
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! The 'caption' configuration somehow produced a weird overfull hbox in another chapter that I could get rid off, therefore I did not include that....

Comment: @Zepp, you can change caption setup locally. See addendum ro answer (will appear soon).

Comment: @Zepp, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the hint, I also added `[font=small, labelfont=bf, format=plain]` to the caption options to make them look more nicely.

Comment: @Zepp, very good! In this case you should remove this option from caption settings used in in `wrapfigure`. Happy TeX-ing!

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to fit an arbitrary image into the available space at the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[23]{r}{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the cumulative sum.}
\vskip\floatsep
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.png}
\caption{An example of the visualization of the distribution.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\paragraph{Cumulative Sum} visually inspects the similarity between the distributions per column, the cumulative sum of each column for both $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ on top of each other are plotted.
This gives a thorough understanding of a column with just one plot, and works for both categorical and continuous columns. Note that this plot does not give any insights into the relations between columns, giving it limited representational power for the whole table. 

\paragraph{Distribution} 
simply shows the distribution of the values of each column plotted with the value on the x-axis and the probability on the y-axis. The bar chart in the background of the figure shows how often values from a certain range (bin) appeared in this specific column of each, $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$.

\paragraph{Correlations} is the fourth visualization. It shows a association table for the real and synthetic data. It gives a clear understanding of what columns have associations with each other, and shows where the synthetic data diverges, indicating struggles that the model had with learning this relationship. Associated columns are coloured in red, disassociated columns in blue. For univariate datasets like the MonthlyMilkProduction dataset this plot was not being created, as it would just be completely red as this dataset only contains one column.

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\setbox0=\vbox{\caption{An example of the visualization of the correlations via an association table.}
\label{fig:exampleasso}}%
\centering
\includegraphics[height={\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal-\ht0-\dp0-2\intextsep}]{example-image.png}
\unvbox0
\end{figure}

%\hrule
\end{document}
```